# Azure Graph DB and Gremlin API

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am creating an elementary graph in Azure Cosmos DB and Graph API using Gremlin.

A fundamental use case is mapping a Node to multiple relationship vertices. For example,

```
Person A -> hasDriver -> DriverName
Person A -> hasButler -> ButlerName
Person A -> hasChef -> ChefName
......
```

How do I write a query that can traverse all "relationships" for Person A and their associated details?

I want to find all the role names that cater to Person A - without having to specify the relationships explicitly. Is that possible?

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've tried, expected vs actual output, errors, etc.

Comment: To traverse the graph, you have to provide the Relationship name (Edge name) in the query.
By usingGremlin's `outE` step to find all the out-edges from value that you mention then traversing to the in-vertices from those edges using Gremlin's `inV` step:
`g.V().hasLabel('lable').has('property', 'value').outE('relatioship').inV().hasLabel('lable')`
Reference: [Traverse your Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph/create-graph-console#traverse-your-graph)